# Using External data source on Dynamics CRM

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm creating an Entity in Dynamics CRM 2015 and I want to add new Lookup field and bind that Lookup to an external data source using OData services or other methods that allow me to read data.

Is it possible technically or I'm in the wrong path to **read data from external data source** and use it in Dynamics CRM.

I also have no experience in Dynamics CRM SDK, If it is possible by using SDK please tell which topics I should search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup fields are the foreign key references of Dynamics CRM. They can only reference records in entities that are part of the CRM data model. When you need a reference to an external resource, the most flexible option would be to add a `String` field.

However, your integration would need to be built with custom software.